# How to find the point on a circle when a point within it is projected out on to it?

Tags: python, math

I need to find the coordinates of a point on a circle (point b in the picture) using the variables shown in the picture.

[image]

I know this is quite a maths related problem but i'm writing the program which this is going to be part of in python.
I've tried the following code and had no luck, i've check the angle its passing though and that's correct. I've also tried the angle in radians and degrees both with no luck.

```
    int_x = r * math.cos(angle)
    int_y = r * math.sin(angle)
```

Please ask any questions about the problem

Thank you

Comment: Are the coordinates of `O` at `(0, 0)`?

Comment: The question is confusing.  Either `theta` or `a` are unnecessary to find `b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the position of `angle` in the diagram, if you were to draw a triangle that encloses `angle`, you'd find that `int_x` is `opposite` the `angle` and `int_y` is adjacent, which means you have your equations flipped (i.e. `int_x = r * sin.cos(angle)` )

Comment: Thank you very much i've spotted my error and corrected it and now the code is working a charm! Thank you.

Comment: @FinnHunt Be careful that theta is calculated by `atan2`, otherwise you can get surprises when `a` is on the Y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

If the circle center is known to be `(c_x, c_y)` and the point `a` is at `(a_x, a_y)`. Then we simply construct a line from the center through point `a` of length `r`. This is simply a similar triangle. We compute the hypotenuse of the triangle to be

`h = sqrt((a_x - c_x)^2 + (a_y-c_y)^2)`

and then we know that

`(b_x, b_y) = (c_x + (a_x - c_x) * r/h, c_y + (a_y - c_y) * r/h)`.

Then you don't need to worry about angles at all! Hope that helps.

Comment: This answer makes most sense, as the problem description with only a picture doesn't tell whether theta is between 0 and 2 pi, nor whether it's sign changes if it would be to the left, nor whether theta would always be measured starting from the up-direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i'm going to try it now!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment (not enough rep), so this answer is only to indicate that in Changming's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59636967/12575476, it should be r/h instead of h/r (twice).